# Why such a different compilers behavior?

Tags: c++, stl, clang++, std-ranges, godbolt

The code below provides completely different results with different compilers and environments.

1. With the Visual Studio 2022 (recent version, x64 compiler v19.37) it compiles just fine and outputs the results with some lines of numbers (don’t focus on them, the question is not about the algorithm or output; the key is that the output is provided).
2. With [godbolt.org | x64 msvc v19.latest](https://godbolt.org/z/z4r8efxov) and the `/std:c++latest` option explicitly set it compiles, but provides very long assembler dump (really, huge) and no output at all.
3. With [godbolt.org | x86-64c clang 17.0.1](https://godbolt.org/z/voK7cWcY3) and the ‘-std=c++23’ option explicitly set it doesn’t compile with long list of error messages.

What kind of error makes this code causing so different compilers behavior?

```cpp
#include <execution>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

auto comp = [](auto&& a, auto&& b) {
    return std::tie(std::get<0>(a), std::get<1>(a)) <
        std::tie(std::get<0>(b), std::get<1>(b)); };

auto proj = [](auto&& v) { return v; };

int main()
{
    std::vector values = { 7,3,9,2,4,7 };
    std::vector indexes = { 0,1,2,3,4,5 };

    auto rng = std::ranges::views::zip(indexes, values);

    std::ranges::sort(rng, comp, proj);

    for (auto i : indexes) {
        for (int vi = 0; vi <= i; ++vi) {
            std::cout << values[vi] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

BTW, they say that ranges were invented particularly to make error messages simpler and more specific. If somebody can explain how you trace these clang error messages here to figure out the problem root cause, I would be thankful, since I am totally lost in this "spaghetti".

**Error Messages**

```
In file included from <source>:4:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4558:14: error: type constraint differs in template redeclaration
 4558 |     template<copy_constructible _Fp, input_range... _Ws>
      |              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4458:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>::_Iterator<true>' requested here
 4458 |     { return _Iterator<true>(__detail::__tuple_transform(ranges::begin, _M_views)); }
      |              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:979:23: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>::begin' requested here
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:979:6: note: in instantiation of requirement here
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:977:32: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
  977 |       concept __member_begin = requires(_Tp& __t)
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  978 |         {
      |         ~
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  980 |         };
      |         ~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:112:50: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept '__member_begin<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' requested here
  112 |         requires is_array_v<remove_reference_t<_Tp>> || __member_begin<_Tp>
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:112:50: note: (skipping 4 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:501:21: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
  501 |     concept range = requires(_Tp& __t)
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  502 |       {
      |       ~
  503 |         ranges::begin(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  504 |         ranges::end(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  505 |       };
      |       ~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:1059:12: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept 'range<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' requested here
 1059 |   template<range _Range>
      |            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:1059:12: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
 1059 |   template<range _Range>
      |            ^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_algo.h:1793:17: note: while checking constraint satisfaction for template 'borrowed_iterator_t<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' required here
 1793 |       constexpr borrowed_iterator_t<_Range>
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:22: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator()' [with _Range = zip_view<all_t<vector<int, allocator<int>> &>, all_t<vector<int, allocator<int>> &>> &, _Comp = (lambda at <source>:6:13), _Proj = (lambda at <source>:10:13)]
   19 |     std::ranges::sort(rng, comp, proj);
      |                      ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4829:12: note: previous template declaration is here
 4829 |   template<copy_constructible _Fp, input_range... _Vs>
      |            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4558:14: error: type constraint differs in template redeclaration
 4558 |     template<copy_constructible _Fp, input_range... _Ws>
      |              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4458:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>::_Iterator<false>' requested here
 4458 |     { return _Iterator<true>(__detail::__tuple_transform(ranges::begin, _M_views)); }
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:979:23: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>::begin' requested here
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:979:6: note: in instantiation of requirement here
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:977:32: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
  977 |       concept __member_begin = requires(_Tp& __t)
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  978 |         {
      |         ~
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  980 |         };
      |         ~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:112:50: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept '__member_begin<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' requested here
  112 |         requires is_array_v<remove_reference_t<_Tp>> || __member_begin<_Tp>
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:112:50: note: (skipping 4 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:501:21: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
  501 |     concept range = requires(_Tp& __t)
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  502 |       {
      |       ~
  503 |         ranges::begin(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  504 |         ranges::end(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  505 |       };
      |       ~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:1059:12: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept 'range<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' requested here
 1059 |   template<range _Range>
      |            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:1059:12: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
 1059 |   template<range _Range>
      |            ^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_algo.h:1793:17: note: while checking constraint satisfaction for template 'borrowed_iterator_t<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' required here
 1793 |       constexpr borrowed_iterator_t<_Range>
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:22: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator()' [with _Range = zip_view<all_t<vector<int, allocator<int>> &>, all_t<vector<int, allocator<int>> &>> &, _Comp = (lambda at <source>:6:13), _Proj = (lambda at <source>:10:13)]
   19 |     std::ranges::sort(rng, comp, proj);
      |                      ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4829:12: note: previous template declaration is here
 4829 |   template<copy_constructible _Fp, input_range... _Vs>
      |            ^
2 errors generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
In file included from <source>:4:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4558:14: error: type constraint differs in template redeclaration
 4558 |     template<copy_constructible _Fp, input_range... _Ws>
      |              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4458:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>::_Iterator<true>' requested here
 4458 |     { return _Iterator<true>(__detail::__tuple_transform(ranges::begin, _M_views)); }
      |              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:979:23: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>::begin' requested here
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:979:6: note: in instantiation of requirement here
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:977:32: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
  977 |       concept __member_begin = requires(_Tp& __t)
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  978 |         {
      |         ~
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  980 |         };
      |         ~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:112:50: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept '__member_begin<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' requested here
  112 |         requires is_array_v<remove_reference_t<_Tp>> || __member_begin<_Tp>
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:112:50: note: (skipping 4 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:501:21: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
  501 |     concept range = requires(_Tp& __t)
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  502 |       {
      |       ~
  503 |         ranges::begin(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  504 |         ranges::end(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  505 |       };
      |       ~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:1059:12: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept 'range<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' requested here
 1059 |   template<range _Range>
      |            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:1059:12: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
 1059 |   template<range _Range>
      |            ^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_algo.h:1793:17: note: while checking constraint satisfaction for template 'borrowed_iterator_t<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' required here
 1793 |       constexpr borrowed_iterator_t<_Range>
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:22: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator()' [with _Range = zip_view<all_t<vector<int, allocator<int>> &>, all_t<vector<int, allocator<int>> &>> &, _Comp = (lambda at <source>:6:13), _Proj = (lambda at <source>:10:13)]
   19 |     std::ranges::sort(rng, comp, proj);
      |                      ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4829:12: note: previous template declaration is here
 4829 |   template<copy_constructible _Fp, input_range... _Vs>
      |            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4558:14: error: type constraint differs in template redeclaration
 4558 |     template<copy_constructible _Fp, input_range... _Ws>
      |              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4458:30: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>::_Iterator<false>' requested here
 4458 |     { return _Iterator<true>(__detail::__tuple_transform(ranges::begin, _M_views)); }
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:979:23: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>>::begin' requested here
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:979:6: note: in instantiation of requirement here
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:977:32: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
  977 |       concept __member_begin = requires(_Tp& __t)
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  978 |         {
      |         ~
  979 |           { __decay_copy(__t.begin()) } -> input_or_output_iterator;
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  980 |         };
      |         ~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:112:50: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept '__member_begin<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' requested here
  112 |         requires is_array_v<remove_reference_t<_Tp>> || __member_begin<_Tp>
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:112:50: note: (skipping 4 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:501:21: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
  501 |     concept range = requires(_Tp& __t)
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  502 |       {
      |       ~
  503 |         ranges::begin(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  504 |         ranges::end(__t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  505 |       };
      |       ~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:1059:12: note: while checking the satisfaction of concept 'range<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' requested here
 1059 |   template<range _Range>
      |            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_base.h:1059:12: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
 1059 |   template<range _Range>
      |            ^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ranges_algo.h:1793:17: note: while checking constraint satisfaction for template 'borrowed_iterator_t<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>> &>' required here
 1793 |       constexpr borrowed_iterator_t<_Range>
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:22: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator()' [with _Range = zip_view<all_t<vector<int, allocator<int>> &>, all_t<vector<int, allocator<int>> &>> &, _Comp = (lambda at <source>:6:13), _Proj = (lambda at <source>:10:13)]
   19 |     std::ranges::sort(rng, comp, proj);
      |                      ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/ranges:4829:12: note: previous template declaration is here
 4829 |   template<copy_constructible _Fp, input_range... _Vs>
      |            ^
2 errors generated.
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: *"If somebody can explain how you trace these cland error messages here to figure out the problem..."* **Always post complete error along with your question.**

Comment: It [works](https://godbolt.org/z/ePWWfY8s4) with clang.

Comment: Godbolt can't run code compiled with MSVC, hence no output.

Comment: @user12002570, can you please take a look at the errors at the [godbolt.org | x86-64c clang 17.0.1](https://godbolt.org/z/voK7cWcY3)  (the only case which produces the errors) and help me to figure out what exactly from this "spaghetti" should I copy in the question so that I could make it better? I intentionally avoided this to have the question concise.  If you like, please be my guest to edit so that I could learn the approach for future.

Comment: So it compiles with Clang trunk, but not 17. Likely just another bug, they've been behind on ranges support.

Comment: @DamirTenishev It already [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/ePWWfY8s4) with clang trunk as i said in my previous comment. New features are constantly being added to compilers.

Comment: @DamirTenishev The program also compiles with [clang assertion trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/8MhYKq7fv)

Comment: @user12002570, I did my best to add the error message. Does it help? Is the formatting done properly or could I get something not with such a huge height?

Comment: cland ? clang ?

Comment: @DamirTenishev The formatting is fine.

Comment: @user12002570, it works with trunk. What about 17.0.1. And with your [link](https://godbolt.org/z/ePWWfY8s4) I can't see neither compiler window nor output window and I don't see any options to see them. How could I add one in your representation?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I am a little bit lost with the sentence " Godbolt can't run code compiled with MSVC, hence no output.". Do you mean that I somehow told godbolt that it should run code compiled with MSVC or you just reword my question?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Here is the [demo with output](https://godbolt.org/z/7aanjq8Mz) that you wanted.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, with the  "they've been behind on ranges support", any chance to learn from the error message what is the real cause, which makes clang to fail? What piece of code should I avoid to be portable in such case. I see that in trunk we have better situation, but just to learn how to investigate these error logs, is there any chance to stop the issue causing thing in code?

Comment: @DamirTenishev The error is due to the lack of support in the older version of the compiler. So don't worry about the piece of code to avoid. There is nothing wrong with your code. Next, msvc just doesn't support `output mode`(aka `executor`) on godbolt(). So here also nothing can be done from your side.

Comment: @user12002570, thank you for the output added. How have you done it? I looked throughout all the UI and didn't find neither output window nor the output for compiled code although usually I see the buttons to add them.

Comment: @DamirTenishev Go to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/8Kd3Eq1hq). Then click on icon saying `Add New` and then click on `Execution only`. Then a new window will open. Then in this new window, change the compiler to the `clang trunk`. Additionally in this same window, add a flag `-std=c++23`

Comment: @user12002570, "msvc just doesn't support output mode(aka executor) on godbolt()". Thank you, this helped, I just noticed this.

Comment: @user12002570, thank you; this part worked, but the output is still on a separate tab, while I usually have it in the bottom of the executor like [here](https://godbolt.org/z/voK7cWcY3) and I still don't have any idea how to extract/drag it from there.

Comment: Why do you always include `<execution>` instead of `<algorithm>` which contains `ranges::sort`?

Comment: Also, if you use Clang you should prefer libc++ instead of libstdc++, your code compiles fine with `-stdlib=libc++`.

Comment: @康桓瑋, on <execution>, since in other pieces of code I accustomed to use execution policies (which unfortunately are not supported in ranges, so far) and this header works for both. Somehow this one survived when I cleaned the list of headers instead of <algorithm>. Frankly, I asked myself about the same when I revised the code before sharing the next time, and decided that it could have crept with somebody else code snipped; not sure. Why would you prefer <algorithm> so much that you have asked?

Comment: @康桓瑋, "Also, if you use Clang you should prefer libc++ instead of libstdc++, your code compiles fine with -stdlib=libc++". Do you mean with 17.0.1 version, as well or again this goes with the trunk only?

Comment: @康桓瑋, I finally found the reason for using `<execution>` instead of `<algorithm>`. The former has `std::iota` and the latter doesn't. The `std::iota` is missing here, but very handy in examples, so I prefer to stay with `<execution>` instead of including additionally `<numeric>`.